# Accessing an EJB3 bean in a jar from an independently deployed war (not packaged in ear)

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0

For some reasons, I would like to deploy my application as two separate artifacts: **Users-ejb.jar** and **Users-war.war**, not packaged in the same **ear** (but still, deployed in the *same* JBoss AS 7.1 instance). In the **Users-war.war** I have a backing bean (annotated as a JSF managed bean) where I wish to inject an EJB3 packaged in the **Users-ejb.jar**. The simple **@EJB** injection that worked when everything was packaged in a single **ear** no longer works when the **Users-ejb.jar** and the **Users-war.war** are deployed seperately.

A narrowed-down simplified example of my setup follows:

**EJB3 bean**

```
import javax.ejb.*;

(...)

@Stateless(name="userFacade")
@Local(IUserFacadeLocal.class)
@Remote(IUserFacadeRemote.class)
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> implements IUserFacadeLocal, IUserFacadeRemote {
```

**Backing bean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

import entities.User;
import facades.IUserFacadeRemote;
import facades.IUserFacadeLocal;

@ManagedBean(name="indexBackingBean")
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBackingBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB(beanName="userFacade")
    private IUserFacadeLocal userFacade;
```

I've tried various combinations like declaring the type of the EJB3 bean in the backing bean as IUserFacadeRemote (as opposed to IUserFacadeLocal) but they all fail with the same exception when the **Users-war.war** module is deployed:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
JBAS014543: No EJB found with interface of type 'facades.IUserFacadeLocal' and
 name 'userFacade' for binding controllers.IndexBackingBean/userFacade
```

The **Users-ejb.jar** is deployed to JBoss AS 7.1 without any complains but when the **Users-war.war** is deployed, JBoss complains that it can't find the bean he's supposed to inject.

However, I am able to obtain a reference to the EJB3 bean using JNDI using:

```
String jndiName = "java:global/Users-ejb/userFacade!facades.IUserFacadeRemote";
this.userFacade = (IUserFacadeRemote) new InitialContext().lookup(jndiName);
```

Despite that, the @EJB injection doesn't seem to work.

**UPDATE:**
I followed the suggestion give below by [Tom Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116639/tom-anderson) and the injection that does work is the:

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:global/Users-ejb/userFacade!facades.IUserFacadeRemote")
```

which if I understand correctly uses the vendor-specific mappedName attribute. I couldn't get the injection to work in a vendor-independent way.

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916045/how-can-i-inject-an-ejb-from-an-other-application-on-the-same-glassfish-server/11926283#11926283). It's for GlassFish but maybe can help...

Comment: Did either of my suggestions work? I'm very curious to know!

Comment: I am sidetracked on another issue at the moment, will definitely report when I try your suggestions. At the moment I am using the JNDI lookup work-around I have added at the end of my post.

Comment: @TomAnderson see the update on my post and my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish i understood this area of the EE spec well enough to give you a definitive answer, but i don't.

The [JBoss EJB documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/1.0.7/html/EJB_Ref_Resolution.html) has this to say:

> - The @EJB annotation also has a mappedName() attribute. The specification leaves this a vendor specific metadata, but JBoss recognizes mappedName() as the global JNDI name of the EJB you are referencing. If you have specified a mappedName(), then all other attributes are ignored and this global JNDI name is used for binding.
> - If you specify @EJB with no attributes defined [...] Then the following rules apply:
>
>   - The EJB jar of the referencing bean is searched for an EJB with the interface, used in for @EJB injection. If there are more than one EJB that publishes same business interface, then an exception is thrown. If there is only one bean with that interface then that one is used.
>   - Search the EAR for EJBs that publish that interface. If there are duplicates, then an exception is thrown. Otherwise the matching bean is returned.
>   - Search globally in JBoss for an EJB of that interface. Again, if duplicates, an exception is thrown.
> - @EJB.beanName() corresponds to . If the beanName() is defined, then use the same algorithm as @EJB with no attributes defined except use the beanName() as a key in the search. An exception to this rule is if you use the ejb-link '#' syntax. The '#' syntax allows you to put a relative path to a jar in the EAR where the EJB you are referencing lives. See spec for more details

The "Search globally in JBoss for an EJB of that interface" certainly suggests that an injection like the one you wrote should work. Indeed, that it should work without the `beanName`. However, my suspicion is that from the point of view of a component in the WAR, a component in the EJB-JAR is remote, and therefore you will need to use the remote interface.

So, the first thing i'd try is:

```
@EJB
private IUserFacadeRemote userFacade;
```

Without a `beanName`, in case that's making trouble. It sounds like you've tried that, though.

If the normal approach to injection doesn't work, i might fall back to trying an injection via a `mappedName`, which in JBoss is a global JNDI name. So:

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:global/Users-ejb/userFacade!facades.IUserFacadeRemote")
private IUserFacadeRemote userFacade;
```

This is obviously rather ugly.

Anyway, good luck!

**EDIT**: Something else you could try is to use a qualified relative `beanName` which explicitly names the EJB-JAR:

```
@EJB(beanName = "Users-ejb.jar#userFacade")
private IUserFacadeRemote userFacade;
```

Because the WAR and EJB-JAR are not packaged in an EAR, this might need to be:

```
@EJB(beanName = "../Users-ejb.jar#userFacade")
private IUserFacadeRemote userFacade;
```

But by this point i'm just guessing.

**EDIT STRIKES BACK**: We may have overlooked something very simple. The [`lookup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html#lookup%28%29) attribute of the `@EJB` annotation lets you specify "A portable lookup string containing the JNDI name for the target EJB component", hence:

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/Users-ejb/userFacade!facades.IUserFacadeRemote")
private IUserFacadeRemote userFacade;
```

Might work. This is essentially a portable version of the JBoss-specific use of `mappedName`.

Comment: OK, so "@EJB" does _not_ work. "@EJB" with the mappedName attribute you provided _does_ work. So it seems that one is left with only a vendor-dependent way to perform this injection or having to use JNDI lookup. It is a bit unsettling to use a work-around without an understanding of why the other simpler annotations didn't do the trick. I may have to take this to JBoss forums to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Edited with yet another idea.

Comment: I don't think the reference to "JBoss EJB documentation" is correct for Jboss 7.1. I debugged the server and it only looks inside current application. It never searches globally.

Answer (score 0):

I have been testing this scenario in Wildfly and found that it will work with local interfaces as described above if there is a jboss-deployment-structure.xml inside of the war pointing to the ejb. Otherwise a ClassNotFoundException is thrown as the war above can't really "know" about the ejbs classes due to the modular class loading in JBoss and Wildfly. The content of the file should be:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.Users-ejb.jar" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

And then the JSF bean can use:

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/Users-ejb/userFacade!facades.IUserFacadeRemote")
private IUserFacadeLocal userFacade;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @TomAnderson said, the standard way to achieve cross-artifact lookup is the [`lookup` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html#lookup%28%29) of the `@EJB` annotation.

Here's a complete Maven project to illustrate how this works:
https://github.com/mrts/remote-ejb-injection

You don't need to use the `name` attribute of the EJB class, providing the class name in lookup is sufficient. Quoting from the example above:

```
// in API JAR
@Remote
public interface HelloService { ... }

// in EJB JAR
@Stateless
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService { ... }

// in WAR
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/service-ear/service-ejb-impl/HelloServiceImpl!" +
                  "ee.mrts.service.HelloService")
    private HelloService helloService;

    ...
}
```

(So, using `HelloServiceImpl` directly in `lookup` Just Works™.)