# How to inject EJB from different EAR in same glassfish

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have been trying to implement this design for couple of days ago and had no success. (before continuing I tell that I have read this article "[How can I inject an EJB from an other application on the same GlassFish Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916045/how-can-i-inject-an-ejb-from-an-other-application-on-the-same-glassfish-server)" and other than glassfish-ejb-jar.xml I tried everything in it )

I have 2 ear application. test.ear is my main app which I want to test it, but I don't want to add any remote interfaces in this project, so I created another .ear(automation.ear) which contains remote interfaces and inject EJBs from test.ear . so my standalone application calls automation app and can not access test application directly.

each application contains these modules: entities, ejb , ear (for example automation application contains :automation-entities, automation-ejb, automation-ear)

here is my journey :
(I deployed test.ear before all these attempts)
-first try: I added test.ejb with ejb type as a maven dependency to automation-ejb pom.xml and injected EJB of test.ear in one of the beans of automation project and gave it a mappedName; it worked however I realized that it is a false positive and it actually doesn't go to the implementation of test.ear. it uses the copy it has (because of dependency)
-  second try: I added a plugin in pom.xml of test.ear to create ejb-client for me (which only contains the interfaces and not the implementation) and added this .jar to automation pom.xml as a dependency, then injected the ejb gave it mappedName and try to deply ; well it complained about not finding the class!--> can't deploy
- third try: I added a copy of the interface I wanted to use(from test.ear) in automation.ear and removed the dependencies in pom.xml of automation. injected EJB and gave it the mappedName; tried to deploy and no luck ! still can't find the class--> can't deploy

Here are my classes:
**test.ear application**

```
package com.ericsson.test.service;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface TestService1 {

    public String TestMethod1();
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package com.ericsson.test.service;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    @Local(TestService1.class)
    @Stateless(name = "TestService1")

    public class TestServiceBean1 implements TestService1{

        @Override
        public String TestMethod1() {
            return "Test Method1";
        }

    }
```

**automation.ear application**

```
@Remote
public interface RemoteInterfaceTest{

    public void doSomething();
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package com.ericsson.test.service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class RemoteInterfaceTestBean implements RemoteInterfaceTest {

    @EJB(mappedName = "Test-Server-Local/test-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestService1/local")
    private TestService1 testService1EJB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomething() {

        try {

            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            TestService1 service1 = (TestService1) ic
                    .lookup("java:global/Test-Server-Local/test-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestService1");
            System.out.println(service1.TestMethod1());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("OOOOOOPPPPPPSSSSSSSSS ! First try");
        }
        try {
            testService1EJB.TestMethod1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("OOOOOOPPPPPPSSSSSSSSS ! Second try");
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the exception I get:

```
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [automation-csdp-remote] : Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=com.ericsson.test.service.RemoteInterfaceTestBean/testService1EJB,Local 3.x interface =com.ericsson.test.service.TestService1,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=Test-Server-Local/test-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/TestService1/local,jndi-name=,refType=Session
```

I have tried played with it like 1000 times, I checked the glass fish and the class is there, why it can not find it ? any idea would be greatly appreciated.

- I am using EJB 3.x , glassfish 3.1.2 , maven 3.0.5, eclipse kepler

Comment: is the interface or class `TestService1` part of the deployment test.ear?

Comment: yes , I have added it as an ejbModule and a dependency to test.ear pom.xml

Comment: Can you please describe how you have deployed your deployments? Because, based on the error I can straight away say that your deployment is not right. Also, I would suggest to check what is the JNDI name of the concrete class that implements `TestService1`

Comment: I finally found the solution! it turned out that JNDI was working properly . the issue was casting. I kept receiving 'proxy' type instead of my desired type. after a lot of investigation I found a workaround . I added my interfaces ( only the interfaces and not the implementation) as a jar file to lib forlder of my domain in glassfish and then it worked.  thanks to all for trying to fix my issue.

Comment: Yes for remote types, you should always inject by interfaces not concrete classes, BTW, for your knowledge I would suggest you to take a look at `no interface session beans(local)`